# Issue with printing a .txt file using getters and setters

Tags: java, eclipse, getter-setter

I have an assignment that requires me to create a class "Employee.java" that contains my getters and setters. The Employee class contains first name, last name, rank, and salary. Then I have a second class called "Prog5.java" that basically needs to print out all my information from a separate text file called "employees.txt".

My question would be:

Am I doing this in the correct way because my code is not operating in the way i desire it to.  Any help/corrections to my code would be greatly appreciated.

here is my Prog5.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Prog5 {

    Scanner inFile = null;

    try{

        inFile = new Scanner(new File("employees.txt"));
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while(inFile.hasNext()){

        String Fname = inFile.next();
        String Lname = inFile.next();
        String rank = inFile.next();
        double salary = inFile.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("%-10s %3d %6.2f\n", Lname, Fname, rank, salary);
    }
    inFile.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my Employee.java:

```
public class Employee {
    private String Fname;
    private String Lname;
    private String rank;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String Fname, String Lname, String rank, double salary){
        this.Fname = Fname;
        this.Lname = Lname;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    //getters and setters
    public String getFname() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        Fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return Lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        Lname = lname;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

If you need to see my .txt file to help me, please let me know and i will edit my post and add it.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: The code in your Prog5 needs to be in the main method

Comment: What do you mean? i didnt create a different method within Prog5. All i have is my main. Im sorry if i sound incompetent as im trying to learn how to code with java and im not up to "par" with everything.

Comment: `All i have is my main` - I can not see it in the above code

Comment: Oh my god. I added it so it would be within my main, but when i run my code, the output is "File not found". Any recommendations on what i could do to fix that?

Comment: If the file is not in your current directory it will need to be pathed

Comment: Alright, what should i type for that to happen?

Comment: Something like `new File("c:\\temp\\employees.txt")`

Comment: where would i put that within my code?

Comment: replace your cuttent `inFile = new Scanner(new File("employees.txt"));` with it.

Comment: I did that, and im still receiving the same "File not found" error. Is there a certain place i should keep my .txt file? Currently i have it in my src folder.

Comment: So put the path of your `src` folder into the `new File` statement